# Galaxy Stylo encrpted forgot password

Tags: locked-out

I encrypted my device then I changed the password. The encryption password changed too, but I can't remember to what, I thought I changed the password back to what it was. I tried default_password twice and it didn't work. I have 15 guesses left.

I encrypted my Galaxy Stylo phone using Google's encryption option.

Later, I changed my password, then I turned my phone off. I can't remember the password. I'm at the encryption screen with 15 more tries before I'm locked out. I have no idea what to do
I booted in safemode, but that still puts me at the decryption screen

Comment: There's no way around it. I would recommend finding a same/very similar phone, going through the process of encrypting it, it may jog your memory.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the encryption is there for one reason and that is to not let access to the phone's settings and data without a decryption key or password. If it was just the lockscreen passcode, you could've simply factory reset your phone through recovery.

Comment: If it were just a lock-screen protection, one might even be able to just remove it by other means, see our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info).